# Parse negative numbers from string in perl

Tags: perl, parsing, integer, negative-number

How do I parse a negative number from a string in perl? I have this piece of code:

```
print 3 - int("-2");
```

It gives me `5`, but I need to have `3`. How do I do it?

Comment: 3 minus negative 2 *is* 5.

Comment: That's what I get for posting a question on stackoverflow before thinking about what I'm asking. Thank you all for your answers and comments! I would have deleted this question, but I can't.

Comment: that kind of question is important to preserve, because it will happen to other people, too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perl will automatically convert between strings and numbers as needed; no need for an int() operation unless you actually want to convert a floating point number (whether stored as a number or in a string) to an integer.  So you can just do:

```
my $string = "-2";
print 3 - $string;
```

and get 5 (because 3 minus negative 2 *is* 5).

Answer (score 5):

Well, 3 - (-2) really is 5. I'm not really sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to filter out negative values, why not do something like this:

```
$i = int("-2")
$i = ($i < 0 ? 0 : $i);
```

This will turn your negative values to 0 but lets the positive numbers pass.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be parsing it correctly. 
3 - (-2) **is** 5.
If it was mistakenly parsing -2 as 2 then it would have output 3 - 2 = 1. 
No matter how you add/subtract 2 from 3, you will never get 3.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking of some other function instead of 'int'.

try:

```
 use List::Util qw 'max';

 ...

 print 3 - max("-2", 0);
```

if you want to get 3 as result.

Regards

rbo